# Diffrence b/w Google Work account and Google service account

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I am trying to access events from google calendar and I came across on solution 
 [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master), This script require [google service account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts), I have one doubt is google service account is free or require [Google Work account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6375836?hl=en) for my application ?

Answer (score 0):

Discussed in [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) and shown as the best alternative:

> If you have a Google Apps domain—if you use Google Apps for Work, for example—an administrator of the Google Apps domain can authorize an application to access user data on behalf of users in the Google Apps domain. For example, an application that uses the Google Calendar API to add events to the calendars of all users in a Google Apps domain would use a service account to access the Google Calendar API on behalf of users. Authorizing a service account to access data on behalf of users in a domain is sometimes referred to as "delegating domain-wide authority" to a service account.

Furthermore,

> To delegate domain-wide authority to a service account, first enable domain-wide delegation for an existing service account in the Service accounts section of the Developers Console's Permissions page or create a new service account with domain-wide delegation enabled.

Lastly, setting up of service account is is **automatically** done  upon creating your project while your application runs on Google App Engine.

Comment: I need to access calendar events and I have developed script for same using service account, So I require work account , I don't need administrator account.